# condition for scalars for existence of a vector x

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a n dimensional vector space .  Let $m < n$ and $y_1,y_2,....y_m$ be m linear functions in $V'$. What are the conditions on the scalars $\alpha_1,.....\alpha_m$ so that there exist a non-zero vector x such that  $y_i(x) = \alpha_i$ ?

The idea on which I was thinking was using annihilators but couldn't proceed further.